# BizTalk File.Username not set

Tags: biztalk

I have created a BizTalk Application that uses a ReceivePort of Type: File, and in the orchestration I'm trying to get the message property 'FILE.Username' as below, but it's value is not set.

```
if (FILE.Username exists msgFile)  
     varUsername = msgFile(FILE.Username);
```

The ReceiveLocation is mapped to a shared folder and I have set the Authentication Credentials to a different user.

Anyone knows why the FILE.Username is not set with the username that I configured in the ReceiveLocation (actually the FILE.Username not even exists in the message properties) ?

Other Properties are set (like FILE.ReceivedFileName and FILE.FileCreationTime) and I can obtain their values normally.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

The username supplied on receive location Authentication tab are stored in SSO database for security reasons. FILE.Username context property is only useful if you are using dynamic send port to send the file and wants to set the property in pipeline or orchestration, otherwise it won't be available in context.